# QGIS Graphic Modeler not including all GRASS algorithms - How to include v.out.ogr?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-modeler, qgis-grass-plugin

I'm using QGIS 2.18,12 with the GRASS module 7.2.1 on Windows. When building a model in QGIS , I am not able to see all the algorithms possible under thr GRASS module, that are indeed available **within** QGIS, but simply not in the graphic modeler. Specifically, I need to use v.out.ogr (screenshot attached).

How can I include this in the modeler?

It is vital that I have v.out.ogr built-in the modeler, and not select the function via  Plugins > GRASS, and then from the GRASS Tools: File management> export from GRASS> export vector from GRASS.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new description file in your `C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description` directory (or wherever you installed it) and add the parameters used by the tool. Create a new text file and use the following:

```
v.out.ogr
Exports a vector map layer to any of the supported OGR vector formats.
Vector (v.*)
ParameterVector|input|Name of input vector map|-1|False
OutputVector|output|Output vector
```

Name the file `v.out.ogr` and save it as a text file. Then place it in the directory mentioned above and restart QGIS. You should now be able to call this tool from the *Processing Toolbox* and from the modeler:

[image: Example]

Comment: Great, worked for me! To people facing similar problems, notice there are two folders ("grass" & "grass7") under "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs", and to make sure to place the description txt file in 'grass7', as mentioned above. Thx!

Comment: @Nimrod - Most welcome! Glad it works and thanks for the comment :)